# Evitar desbordamiento de texto en párrafo dentro de un div

Tags: css

Estoy aprendiendo CSS y estoy tratando de que el texto se quede en la caja.

```css
div {
  background:red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>hsjxjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que el texto del párrafo no se desborde de su contenedor, en este caso el `div` puedes hacer uso de la propiedad `word-wrap` de esta forma:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Además como con esta acción el párrafo será superior al contenedor en altura, podemos seguir manteniendolo dentro de, indicando que el alto ahora sea un `min-height`

De esta forma:

```html
    <style>
      div {
        background:red;
        min-height:100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 5px;
        width:100px; 
        word-break: break-all;
      }
      p {
        background-color: green;
      }
    </style>
    <div>
      <p>
        hsjxjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
      </p>
    </div>
```

Aquí [tienes la referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Por cierto, los `div` ya son [elementos en bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), por tanto agregar lo siguiente esta demás:

```
display:block; /*esto no debe ir, no es necesario*/
```

Comment: añadir word-break: break-all al div como dijistes, me funciono perfecto!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Has uso de `Overflow` y `Text-Overflow`.
El primero controla lo que le sucede al contenido del contenedor.
El segundo, como se muestra o no, ese overflow.

```css
div.a {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

div.a:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<p>Pasa el mouse sobre el contenedor<br>para ver el texto completo</p>

<div class="a">Este texto largo no cabe en su contenedor</div>
```